# NSPredicate to Match the backslash

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate

I want to fetch entity by name matching the string \\xxxx\\yyyy\\zzzz  from core data so i have used NSPredicate like `NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:" name LIKE %@", \\xxxx\\yyyy\\zzzz];` But returns null for some times.I doubt that issue with backslashes so please help me any one.Is any way to fetch this entity from core data?

Comment: what is that \\xxxx\\yyyy\\zzzz

Comment: @karan: Did you have a chance to check the answer? Is that what you were looking for? Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

"LIKE" in a predicate does a simple wildcard matching (with `?` and `*`).
As a consequence, the backslash character has a special meaning and has to be escaped
twice (once for the string literal and once for the "LIKE" operator):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"name LIKE %@", @"\\\\xxxx\\\\yyyy\\\\zzzz"]
```

But if you don't need the wildcard matching then use "==" (or "BEGINSWITH", "CONTAINS") instead:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"name == %@", @"\\xxxx\\yyyy\\zzzz"]
```